# Casting datatype c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, type-conversion

guys I have a field in my database having datatype BIT.
I need to extract this value and perform an IF ELSE condition according to its value.

I tried getting the value as follows

```
   string UStat = "SELECT UserStatus FROM " + MainForm.schema + "Adm.SysUser WHERE USerId ='" + cmbUserID.Text + "'";
            cmd = ccs.CreateCommand();
            ccs.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = UStat;
            int User_stat = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            string user_stat = Convert.ToString(User_stat);
            ccs.Close();
```

At the level of ExecuteScalar i am being notified of an incorrect casting.
Where was I wrong guys ?

Comment: what is the datatype of UserStatus in the DB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data type is Bit, cast it to bool. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,

```
string user_stat = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
if(Convert.ToBoolean(user_stat ))
{
-----
-----
}
```

In side if condition, You will get either true/false

Answer (score 0):

I got it guys ....

i solved it by modifying my codes to

```
  string UStat = "SELECT UserStatus FROM " + MainForm.schema + "Adm.SysUser WHERE USerId ='" + cmbUserID.Text + "'";
            cmd = ccs.CreateCommand();
            ccs.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = UStat;
            bool User_stat = ((bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar()); 
            ccs.Close();
```

Thanks to all that tried to help. Cheers